# fgets and sscanf getting list value twice

Tags: c, fgets, scanf

I'm having trouble with `sscanf` and `fgets` where it seems to be getting the last value input and re reading it back through even though we have come to the end of the file. My code:

```
while (won == 0) {
 char command, input[MAX_LENGTH];
 fgets(input, MAX_LENGTH, stdin);

 sscanf(input, " %c\n", &command);

 printf('%c\n', command);
 check_won();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `sscanf` pattern is `%c %s`, but you're only ever reading `command`.  Is that intentional?  You should consider checking the return value of `fgets` to ensure that it is still actually reading input, and the return value of `sscanf` to ensure that it is indeed reading two elements (and discarding the second one).  If your input is not being parsed and collected correctly, and your `check_won` function is dependent on that input, you will see repeated input because your array will not be being re-initialized.

Try something like this instead?

```
if(fgets(input, MAX_LENGTH, stdin) == NULL) {
    break;
}
```

Comment: Ah, didn't meant to leave the %s in there. It's not in my code, I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Same problem.  You're using a pattern in sscanf with literals in it.  If there's not a preceeding space before the input, sscanf won't read *anything* and `command` will still be uninitialised.  Try `"%c"` instead?

Comment: Oh, even simpler.  You're not checking if `fgets` reads anything.  You need to do your `fgets` inside an 'if' statement that ensures that it returns a non-null return value (I just replicated your problem).

Answer (score 0):

In the format string you have specified 2 elements but you have passed only one argument &command.

> sscanf(input, " %c %s\n", &command);

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is even though `fgets` fails at the `EOF`, your `sscanf` is reading the last value of `input` fetched by `fgets`. So do not do sscanf if `fgets` fails.

Try this

```
    char command, input[MAX_LENGTH];

    while ( won == 0 &&  fgets(input, MAX_LENGTH, stdin) ) {
     sscanf(input, " %c\n", &command);
     printf('%c\n', command);
     check_won();
    }
```